# how to read/see stored array[] mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

i have the next files to store an array[] into a mysql database. Now i would like to create a file to see the stored data, as an info file....like a table with the results or something.

in phpmyadmin database  i see the stored data as:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"sentra b15";i:1;s:10:"sentra b13";}
```

thanks for your time

index.php

```
<html>
<body>


<form action="insert3.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname[]"> <br>
Firstname 2: <input type="text" name="firstname[]"> <br>
Firstname 3: <input type="text" name="firstname[]"> <br>
Firstname 4: <input type="text" name="firstname[]"> <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","inputmultiplicad","inputmultiplicado","inputmultiplicado");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }








$data= $_POST['firstname'];
$values= serialize($data);

$sql="INSERT INTO input_field (firstname)
VALUES
('$values')";




if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the result of php **[serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)** function. Use **[unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)** function to decode it:

```
echo unserialize($str);
```

Comment: xdazz, do you mean echo unserialize($data);can you point me an example of how to?

Answer (score 0):

i think in your case the solution is this:

$data[0]; is going to be your first index or value that you inserted.

$data[1]; is going to be your secind index or value that you inserted.

and there for.....

Comment: hi user3384946,what if i add those input fields dinamically with jquery?, how am i going to know how many inputs fields are there going to be?

Comment: no you dont have to use jquery you can use php like this:`foreach($data as &$item){ echo '$item'; }` $item is going to change till $data finish its array